# Nodejs server with Express not sending responses to HTTP requests from javascript file, but is receiving the requests and processing them

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, xmlhttprequest

So I have a node-js server and an apache server on the same machine, and one of the javascript files is sending an HTTP request to the node-js server. The node-js server receives the file, reads the data, puts it in the database, as it should, but it isn't sending back any status codes or data.

Here is the XHTMLRequest send code snippet,

```
// creates a new http request to be sent to the nodejs server
function createNewUser(username, password, email) {

    // The url is the URL of our local nodejs server
    var userCreateRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    userCreateRequest.open( "POST", "http://<machine's IP>:8080/api/users" );

    // Create json object for user data
    var user = "name="+username+"&password="+password+"&email="+email;
    alert(user);

    // set content type for http request
    userCreateRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    // Event listern for server response
    // userCreateRequest.addEventListener("readystatechange", processRequest, false);

    // Call process request whenever state changes
    userCreateRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
            alert(this.readyState + ", " + this.status);
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

                    var response = this.response;
                    alert(response.name);

            }

    }

    // Send user data to server
    userCreateRequest.send(user);

}
```

And here is the code for the node-js server (with express)

```
router.route('/users')

    .post(function(req, res) { //create a new user

            var user = new User();

            user.name = req.body.name;
            user.password = req.body.password;
            user.email = req.body.email;

            user.save(function(err) { //add user object to database

                    if(err)
                            res.send(err);

                    res.status(200).json(user);

            });

    });
```

As I said above, the code works fine in terms of putting the body of the request in the database and what-not, but the server is not sending back the 200 OK response (or I'm failing to receive it for some reason). The only times I get an alert from onreadystatechange is when it's state 2, status 0, and state 4, status 0.

Comment: `http://<machine's IP>:8080` is it a cross origin request? lookup CORS - express has a cors module, so that's easy

Comment: I'm afraid not, as I mentioned both servers are hosted on the same machine. For some reason though, http://localhost:8080/api/users doesn't work, while specifying the external IP of the machine does...

Comment: same machine ... same port? (8080) if so, why is your request with a FQDN?

Comment: Different ports, the first javascript is running on the default html port, so 80, and the node server is running on 8080. EDIT: FQDN is because localhost:8080 won't work for some reason. I'm not sure why but I can't get it to work, even if I specify app.listen(8080, 'localhost') or app.listen(8080, '127.0.0.1') in my node server.

Comment: So. It's a cors issue

Comment: When using Postman from a different machine I can send the data and get back a 200 OK code though. I don't know if that could still be a CORS error... Sorry I'm relatively new to all of this. I'll try enabling CORS right now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159113/discussion-between-purxiz-and-jaromanda-x).

Comment: yes, it is a cors issue if it's a cross origin request and no cors headers enable the request

Comment: On a separate note. You should return at `res.send(err);` otherwise you will get an error for trying to send back a aresponse twice.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code snippet.

```
user.save(function(err, user) {

                if(err)
                        res.send(err);

                res.status(200).json(user);

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It did end up being a CORS issue. I'm still a little iffy on exactly why, but after configuring the [express/CORS](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) package to allow requests from the IP and port of my apache server, it started working.

My understanding is that cross origin implies a different domain, where-as both of my servers are (as I understand it) on different ports on the same domain.

Either way, enabling CORS fixed the issue. Thank you to Jaromanda X for pointing it out and getting me on the right track.

Comment: Different ports on the same domain still counts as cross-origin: "A web application executes a cross-origin HTTP request when it requests a resource that has a different origin (domain, protocol, or port) from its own." from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)